# Can I make WebBrowser translucent and borderless in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am finding that setting the Opaque value has no effect. Also there is always a border around the WebBrowser.

Comment: Maybe another option. Not sure if it has similar issues... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140363/hosting-browser-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

From the [WPF `WebBrowser` page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN:

> The WebBrowser control internally instantiates the native WebBrowser ActiveX control.

So it's not an actual WPF control... just a wrapper around a native control that allows little customization.

Here's a [blog](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/24/wpf-4-5-%E2%80%93-part-8-no-more-airspace-problems-integrating-wpf-with-win32/) that summarizes what you *can't* do with the ActiveX control pretty well:

> If you add a Win32 component into a wpf application using the hwndhost control you have some limitations:
>
> - Resizing is limited because only the container(hwndhost) will be resized, not the contained component itself.
> - Forget about rotation and skewing.
> - The hosted component is a black hole for your application : always at the top (forget the z-order!).
> - Opacity can’t be applied to an hosted Win32 control.
> - VisualBrush do not work with Win32 controls.

He goes on to explain a work-around that would come with WPF 4.5, but I can't find anywhere that those promised features ever shipped. They don't appear to have.

---

About the border.. when I test it I don't have one. But if you do, I'm guessing there's no way to remove that either.

Here's what I see in a small test project (the `WebBrowser` has a margin of 20px, and it's inside of a `GroupBox` with 20px padding):

[image]

Comment: OK, how about getting rid of the border line?